# How can I disable the sound of a notification?

Tags: android

I record the audio in `RecordService` via the  `suspend fun startRecord(filename:String){...}`, you can see it in Code A.

`startForegroundService()` will be fired when I invoke `fun startRecord(filename:String)`.

I have to display a notification when I need to start a foreground service.

I find that a sound will be played when the notification is displayed. How can I disable the sound when a notification is displayed?

BTW, the sound of the notification is delay, so it will be record by `mRecorder`, so I hope to disable the sound when a notification is displayed.

And more, I hope `mRecorder` not to record the sound of the notification, is there a better way?

**Code A**

```
class RecordService : Service() {

    val CHANNEL_ID = "My Notification"

    private var mRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null

    private val mBinder: IBinder = MyBinder()

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return mBinder
    }

    inner class MyBinder : Binder() {
        val service: RecordService
            get() = this@RecordService
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    private fun startForegroundService() {
        val channel = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "My Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
        }

        (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
            channel
        )

        val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("A service is running in the background")
            .setContentText("Generating random number").build()
        startForeground(1, notification)
    }


    private fun stopForegroundService() {
        stopForeground(true)
    }


    suspend fun startRecord(filename:String){

        startForegroundService()

        mRecorder = MediaRecorder()

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            mRecorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mRecorder?.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

            mRecorder?.setOutputFile(filename);

            mRecorder?.setMaxDuration(1000*60*20); //20 Mins
            mRecorder?.setAudioChannels(1);
            mRecorder?.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
            mRecorder?.setAudioEncodingBitRate(192000);

            mRecorder?.prepare()
            mRecorder?.start()
        }
    }


    fun stopRecord(){
        mRecorder?.stop()
        mRecorder=null

        stopForegroundService()
        play_Alarm_Sound(this, ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD )
    }

}
```

Comment: Change this line `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` to `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.setSound(null)` on `Notification` and `.setSound(null, null)` on `NotificationChannel`:

```
val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("A service is running in the background")
            .setSound(null)
            .setContentText("Generating random number").build()
```

```
val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
            context.getString("My Channel"),
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
notificationChannel.setSound(null, null)
val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager?
notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
```